# Run only the last event on a series of triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

(This is a jQuery/JS question)

I have +/- buttons for product quantity on an eCommerce site.

A click on those, changes the value of a number-input field and then triggers change event for this number-input field (with `quantityInput.change()`), which in turn triggers an ajax to update the cart.

I want to give a chance to the user to click the buttons several times before triggering the ajax.

I now use `setTimeout` to delay the ajax which made the user experience a little bit better, but this is only a half solution as eventually the ajax is triggered as many times as the buttons had been clicked - and this is redundant.

I'm looking for a way to trigger the ajax only on the "last" click - for example, the click which has no subsequent click for 3 seconds.

For example, if the current quantity for a product "Apple" is 1, I want to allow the user to make 3 fast clicks to change it to 4, and only then trigger an ajax to update the cart.

Again, the flow:

Click on +/- buttons ->> number-input value is updated ->> a change event is triggered (with `quantityInput.change()`) ->> an ajax is called.

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: Please share your code. But you can just reset the timeout on each click.

Comment: You can use debounce from jquery for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - on every click, also use `clearTimeout` to clear the existing timeout, if there is one, to ensure that the timeout callback runs only once there have been no clicks for 3 seconds. For example:

```
let timeout;
quantityInput.on('change', () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(someFnThatUsesAjax, 3000);
});
```

(make sure `timeout` is persistent and outside the handler)